# make a matrix from different frequency length files in r

Tags: r, matrix, frequency

I am new in R and I would like your help.

I have 1 main folder with 2 subfolders and in the subfolders are some .txt files. I put them in a list.

The txt files in the subfolders have 2 columns data (frequency table) with different lengths. I want to open all the files (maybe with a loop?) and create a table with the file names and their frequency outcome. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a precise answer without knowing more details, but here is an attempt

First get the names of all txt files in the working directory

```
filenames <- Sys.glob("*.txt")
```

Now you can read them using `read.table` (you'll need to adjust the arguments of `read.table`, like `header`, etc, according to the structure of your txt files)

```
datalist <- lapply(filenames, read.table)
```

Now to each table, append a column `filename` which will store the name of the corresponding file

```
datalist <- Map(function(d, f) transform(d, filename = f), datalist, filenames)
```

Finally, `rbind` them into a single table

```
do.call(rbind, datalist)
```